# How to calculate $\text{Var}(2X)$ where $X$ is a random variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables, variance

Roll a fair die and let $X$ be the number of dots showing on top.
What are $\text{E}(2X)$ and $\text{Var}(2X)$?

Comment: $\text{Var}$ is a quadratic form, so it satisfies $\text{Var}(rX) = r^2 \text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: Show what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2].$$

Consider $Y = 2X.$ Then:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[2X] = 2 \mathbb{E}[X].$$

Moreover:

$$\text{Var}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^2] = \mathbb{E}[(2X-2\mathbb{E}[X])^2] = \mathbb{E}[4(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2] = 4 \text{Var}[X].$$

In general:

$$\text{Var}[aX] = a^2 \text{Var}[X].$$

---

**Addedum**

Recall that $\mathbb{E}[aX] = a \mathbb{E}[X]$.